# How to get branch specific build status with embeddable build status plugin in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, github, build, jenkins-plugins, github-flavored-markdown

I am using the "Embeddable build status" plugin for Jenkins.

I cannot get the build status of a specific branch working, it always shows "not run" status.

I am using the unprotected link:

`[![Build Status](http://ec2-34-251-244-92.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/jenkins/buildStatus/icon?job=vuffeli_api)](http://ec2-34-251-244-92.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/jenkins/job/vuffeli_api/)`

I have given Anonymous viewstatus permissions on jobs globally.
This works fine but as soon as I add the branch information it stops working.
I have tried the following combinations and am at a loss.

`http://ec2-34-251-244-92.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/jenkins/buildStatus/icon?job=vuffeli_api%2Fmaster)`

`http://ec2-34-251-244-92.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/jenkins/buildStatus/icon?job=vuffeli_api%252Fmaster`

`http://ec2-34-251-244-92.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/jenkins/buildStatus/icon?job=vuffeli_api%2Forigin%252Fmaster`

`http://ec2-34-251-244-92.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/jenkins/buildStatus/icon?job=vuffeli_api%2Fvuffeli_api%252Fmaster`

I was expecting the badge to show the status of the master branch but it is grey and displays "not run"

**EDIT 27-05-2019**

A temporary solution has been to have multiple projects in jenkins that filter what branches trigger builds and then show a status for projects that only build and test specific branches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found a better solution than to have statuses displayed for all relevant branches and I have since stopped using jenkins and started using Azure pipelines instead.
If any of you find a solution please submit the answer but for now I will consider this closed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you have `BRANCH` Parameter for this job and then:

```
http://ec2-34-251-244-92.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/job/vuffeli_api/badge/icon?build=firstSuccessful:${params.BRANCH=master}
```

(worked for me)
Note that this feature is supported since v2.0:
https://github.com/jenkinsci/embeddable-build-status-plugin/issues/27

Comment: I'd be interested in latest release branch, which of course I wouldn't want to check manually into a readme file each time